# How to set Back ground image (repeat) in android?

Tags: android, image

I am new to android. i want to set background image for my android app.i have only a small slice of the image.i want to repeat image only horizontally.i tried in two ways.
1.By using bitmap
 when i used bitmap image is repeating in both directions(horizontal and vertical).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/tile_final"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />
```

2.Used background and tileMode in Layout file.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

In above case image in stretching horizontally.

Please help me to fix this issue.

first image is image to repeat and second image is post screen

[image]

[image]

Comment: theres an attribute named "tileMode" " When the tile mode is enabled, the bitmap is repeated. Gravity is ignored when the tile mode is enabled."

Comment: Post ScreenShot Please

Comment: @PratikButani,I have uploaded images.Please check it once.

Comment: Your image height is not equal to your device height. thats why it streached.

Comment: @PratikButani,concern about height is ok. My concern is width.Even i have places horizontal repeat,it is stretching.it is not repeating.

Comment: @gvsvinayak Whats your xml filename?